# Sum up rasters in R

Tags: r

I have 365 rasters (daily_sm2rain data of a year) in .TIF. I would like to create a new raster which is sum of 365 input rasters in R (~ sum of rain in a year). How can I do this?

I tried 
`input=list.files("path_to_data",pattern="*.tif$").` it's ok.

`map <- brick(paste0("path_to_data",input[1]))`
fives:

> Error is "Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Error in
>   .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) :    Cannot
>   create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

```
print(input)
    [1] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-02_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-03_10km.tif"
      [3] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-04_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-05_10km.tif"
      [5] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-06_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-07_10km.tif"
      [7] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-08_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-09_10km.tif"
      [9] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-10_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-11_10km.tif"
     [11] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-12_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-13_10km.tif"
     [13] "daily.rainfall_2018-01-14_10km.tif" "daily.rainfall_2018-01-15_10km.tif
....
361 rows.
```

Comment: Whats the final goal, plot them of writing them to a file?

Comment: Do you know how to read in one raster file? Please show some code so we know where to start.

Comment: See my answere. Does it work for you?

Comment: What do you obtain by just running `paste0("path_to_data",input[1])`?

Answer (score 9):

So close, use:

```
files = list.files("path_to_data",pattern="*.tif$", full.names=TRUE)

rs <- brick(files)
```

or

```
rs <- stack(files)
```

Don't use `map` as name, there're several R functions with the same name.

Then, to create a sum of all your rasters use `calc` function (from `raster` package):

```
rs1 <- calc(rs, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks aldo_tapia so much. It worked.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if you want, closing this topic

Answer (score 2):

You can read the raster in R with the `raster`package.

It can be loaded with `map <- brick("file_path")`. Then you can apply addition operation between your loaded objects. If you have 365 of them, you should read them through a loop.

Comment: Thank Chelmy88 so much. Please give me some details about "through a loop" in R (functions or commands, advanced packages....).

Comment: What is your knowledge in R? I can show you an example, I would need to know how your files are called then

Comment: Hi Chelmy88, I am quite new to R. I tried rasterstack [# input=list.flies("path_to_data",pattern="*.tif$") # stack=raster::stack(input)]. But it didn't work.

Comment: Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

Comment: Should be `list.files` and not `list.flies`, then try `map <- brick(paste0("path_to_data",input[1]))`. What do you get. And what do you get with `print(input)`after running `list.files` (do not hesitate to add it to your question, it is more readable than in comments).

Comment: Thank Chelmy88, I can run. Just add "full.name=TRUE" in input=list.files("path_to_data",pattern="*.tif$",full.name=TRUE). Then # raster::stack(input).